# how can i convert curl script to php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to write php code from a curl script but I think I have some problems

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.mailjet.com/v4/sms-send \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $MJ_TOKEN" \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "From": "InfoSMS",
  "To": "+33600000000",
  "Text": "Hello World!"
}'
```

my code

```
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailjet.com/v4/sms-send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'From' => 'InfoSMS',
    'To' => '+33600000000',
    'Text' => 'Hello World!'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $token;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
var_dump($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

This is the first time I use curl so I really do not know where to start

Thank you for your help

Comment: whats the results from the code above?

Comment: {"ErrorIdentifier":"xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx","ErrorCode":"mj-0002","StatusCode":400,"ErrorMessage":"Malformed JSON, please review the syntax and properties types."}bool(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the parameter array to JSON. If you give `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` an array, it's sent in URL-encoded format, not JSON.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
    'From' => 'InfoSMS',
    'To' => '+33600000000',
    'Text' => 'Hello World!'
)));
```